# Is there a way to change the boot font size?

Tags: boot, screen

On my RPi3B just after the rainbow screen at initial power-up, I see some tiny text on the screen as it starts the boot process (Noobs distro). Later, I see a little larger text before it starts X.

Is there any way of increasing this initial boot font size or is that too early in the boot process (since I've heard there's no BIOS settings in RPis)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you want to change the console font size.
Try changing the following parameters in your config.txt

```
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_group=1
```

This will force VGA. That's what I use in my 5 inches screen.